# Function in bash not working

Tags: bash

My bash: "testing" with a function "query"

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_USER="root"
MY_PASSWORD="my_password"
MY_BD="my_db"
MY_HOME="/home/express"

function query {
    mysql -e $1 -u $MY_USER --password=$MY_PASSWORD $MY_BD
}

case $1 in
"period")
    mysql -e "SELECT cron_period()" -u $MY_USER --password=$MY_PASSWORD $MY_BD;;
"hold")
    query "SELECT cron_hold()";;
*)
    echo "Others";;
esac
```

Test:

```
testing period // Working with complete command
testing hold   // Not working with function query, show commands info of MySQL
```

The problem is when using the function query, but do not know how to correct it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Perhaps you want to quote the `$1` in double-quotes?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this ie, put `$1` in double qoutes:

```
function query {
    mysql -e "$1" -u $MY_USER --password=$MY_PASSWORD $MY_BD
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try putting double quotes around the $1 in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
function query {
    mysql -e ${1} -u $MY_USER --password=$MY_PASSWORD $MY_BD
}
```